# WooCommerce Free Shipping Only Within a 20 Mile Radius of Location

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We have a client who has a Wordpress website with the WooCommerce (Version 4.5.4) plugin installed, and they would like to offer free local shipping for a 20 mile radius from a specific location.

Is this possible? Either through the main WooCommerce plugin, or by an additional plugin?

I've had a bit of a dig around the plugin pages and google, and cant find much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible without an additional plugin. You can define a shipping zone, and in this shipping zone you can define shipping methods.

Comment: Be very careful though because if your using Geo Locate it isnt 100% accurate on your ACTUAL location just the location of your IP - we had these issues once before and ended up using a plugin.

Comment: Where and how? A plugin is going to be required here unless he ants to manually type in ALL the post/zip codes.

Comment: In the UK there would be LOADS im not sure in the US

Comment: I alongside the client are both based in the UK, and there are over 200 post codes in the town where it is based. I was more considering a single postcode (e.g) The warehouse/store and anywhere where the address is inside of a 20 mile radius would be classed as free shipping.